# Sonar plugin, set Technical Debt for a rule in xml

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a plugin that creates a repository and defines rules within it using a xml file with rules defined for example:

```
<rules>
    <rule>
        <key>KEY</key>
        <name>RULE_NAME</name>
        <severity>BLOCKER</severity>
        <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I want to add technical debt information for each rule as this is currently undefined. After some googling I've seen how it can be done when the rule is defined with in java:

```
@Rule(
  key = "KEY",
  name = "RULE_NAME",
  priority = Priority.MAJOR)        
@SqaleSubCharacteristic(RulesDefinition.SubCharacteristics.UNDERSTANDABILITY)
@SqaleConstantRemediation("5min")
```

so I want to add the @SqaleConstantRemediation("5min") to my xml, can I do this and what tag do I use?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQALE definition goes in a different file, but can still be defined via XML. Take a look at how it's done in the PMD plugin: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-pmd/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/sonar/sqale/pmd-model.xml